# Compile Haskell programs to C

Tags: c, haskell, compilation

I have to following Haskell program I'm trying to compile to C.
I've looked at [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1994190/distributing-a-haskell-program-as-c-source), but could not get an answer there.

```
quicksort [] = []
quicksort (p:xs) = (quicksort lesser) ++ [p] ++ (quicksort greater)
  where
    lesser  = filter (<  p) xs
    greater = filter (>= p) xs

main = print(quicksort([5,2,1,0,8,3]))
```

Here's what I tried:

```
$ ghc -C main.hs
```

And what I get is:

```
ghc: the option -C is only available with an unregisterised GHC
Usage: For basic information, try the `--help' option.
```

This is a bit weird because when I look at the help I see this:

> -C        stop after generating C (.hc output)

Comment: Note that you can compile Haskell to object files and C _header_ files using the Foreign Function Interface. These can then just be _linked_ into a C program. This is much better than literally trans-compiling to C source code.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Compiling to C is now a special-purpose trick, used primarily for bootstrapping on new architectures. Consequently by default it is not supported. [The GHC wiki](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Building/Unregisterised) has some instructions for building GHC yourself with this support enabled; the chief difference between a standard build and a build that enables compiling to C is to configure with the `--enable-unregisterised` flag. See also the [full list of pages on building GHC](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Building) -- it is quite complicated, so you'll want to keep this handy if you decide to do so.

Answer (score 11):

That option is ancient.

Serveral years ago, GHC used to compile via C, but no longer does that in normal scenarios. Instead of generating C code and compiling that with `gcc`, nowadays GHC uses its own native code generator (or LLVM).

Technically, it is possible to compile GHC itself as "unregisterised" to re-enable that option. This requires a custom build of GHC from its source code. This will however produce a rather inefficient C code. Pragmatically, this is only done when cross-compiling or when porting GHC to a new architecture.