# Compile Haskell programs to LLVM IR

Tags: haskell, llvm-ir

According to [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52037888/compile-haskell-programs-to-c) compilation of Haskell programs to C is no longer (officially) supported. So I wanted to explore the option of compiling Haskell programs to LLVM IR. I chose the same program of the mentioned post:

```
quicksort [] = []
quicksort (p:xs) = (quicksort lesser) ++ [p] ++ (quicksort greater)
  where
    lesser  = filter (<  p) xs
    greater = filter (>= p) xs

main = print(quicksort([5,2,1,0,8,3]))
```

and then tried to compile it to LLVM IR with:

```
$ ghc -fllvm main.hs
```

Then I get this error regarding the LLVM version:

```
<no location info>: error:
    Warning: Couldn't figure out LLVM version!
             Make sure you have installed LLVM 3.7
ghc: could not execute: opt-3.7
```

When I check my opt version it's 3.8.0, which is bigger:

```
$ opt --version
LLVM (http://llvm.org/):
  LLVM version 3.8.0
  DEBUG build with assertions.
  Built Jun 20 2018 (14:59:34).
  Default target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
  Host CPU: broadwell
```

So what's going on? **could ghc expect exactly version 3.7.0 and only that?!**

**EDIT**:

After installing llvm 3.7.0 and copying `opt` and `llc` to have 3.7 suffixes:

```
$ cp opt opt-3.7
$ cp llc llc-3.7
```

compilation to llvm goes without errors, using this line:

```
$ ghc -keep-llvm-files main.hs
```

and a file called main.ll is created.

Comment: Here GHC 8.4.3 requires LLVM 5.0. I guess each GHC version wants its own LLVM, but I'm unsure about it.

Comment: Yes The LLVM IR is notoriously unstable with no formal spec (but a reasonable english reference).  When patching a parser for the bitcode I've had to look at the source code to LLVM quite a bit to get clarity on issues.  Similarly with the seemingly meaningless twiddles of human readable LLVM IR syntax between versions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, GHC expects an exact version of LLVM. The LLVM internals change very quickly, and so GHC (like many other tools which target or use LLVM) takes a very conservative approach to versioning of those tools.

Comment: I've edited my question after installing llvm-3.7.0 which now compiles without errors ... but I can't find the generated llvm IR file if one was indeed created ...

Comment: @OrenIshShalom See [the fine manual](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/flags.html#keeping-intermediate-files).

Comment: great it works! one last question I promise: I edited the question again to try to run the generated *.bc file (with llvm-as from *.ll) but it misses the main function which was there in the original Haskell version ... any idea where it went?

Comment: @OrenIshShalom Dunno, I've never played with LLVM before, believe it or not. Might want to open a fresh question with the details. As an aside, what you've done here twice now (editing your question to change what you're asking) is generally frowned upon on SO: edits to clarify your question are fine, but if you come up with new questions as a result of what you learn, those should go in a fresh question instead.

Comment: Removed second EDIT altogether, and kept the first one indicating the exact command line that did work.